# git - change local project folder after update Laravel

Tags: git, github, laravel-5.3

I'm new to git, so this may seem like a simple question.
I'm working on Laravel 5.2 project with many git commits, Now I've migrated Laravel version to 5.3 with it's new folder structure, copying files from the old project and make `git init` and 3 git commits.

How to push these new commits of the new Laravel 5.3 project to the **same** old remote repo which I used with Laravel 5.2 ?

Comment: When you did your `git init` did you do it in the same directory as the old repo?

Comment: I did `git init` in the newly installed laravel 5.3 folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by copying `.git` folder along with `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` from the old repo to the new project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force push to the old repository; DANGER! This will OVERWRITE the old repo, replacing the history of the old repo with only the 3 commits you have in the new one (after the `git init`). You write this as (assuming your main branch is `master`):

```
git push --force [remote_URL] master
```

If you're not sure what `[remote_URL]` is, you can run the following in the old (5.2) repo:

```
git remote get-url [repo_name]
```

(`[repo_name]` is likely `origin`.)

To simplify future pushes, you can also add the old repo as a remote:

```
git remote add [repo_name] [remote_URL]
```

Then force push to that:

```
git push --force [remote_name] master
```

Comment: thanks @DopplerShift for your answer, but I solved this problem by copying `.git` folder along with `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` from the old repo to the new repo.